# Does a waveform of frequency $f+\Delta f$ beat against a wave of frequency $2f$?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference, superposition

In the elementary treatment of waves, [beating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) occurs between two waves of similar frequencies because
$$\cos(2\pi f_1 t)+\cos(2\pi f_2 t) = 2\cos(2\pi \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}t)\cos(2\pi \frac{f_1-f_2}{2}t)$$
and so you have this envelope function of frequency $(f_1 - f_2)/2$.

Here, I plot (in blue) $\sin(t) + \sin(1.01t)$ and (in orange) $\sin(t) + \sin(\frac{1.01}{n} t)$ for $n = 2$.
[image: Beating of waves]

The orange curve appears to have an envelope with period that is the same as the beating of sine waves with $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2 = 1.01$ (i.e. the blue curve). How is this explained?  I'm most interested in the case where $n = 2$, but can something be generalized to arbitrary integer $n$?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but the answer to the question in the title is simply no. For no phase do two frequencies $f, 2f$ beat. This principle is used to tune an orchestra across instruments in different registers or octaves.

Comment: I edited the title for clarity.  I meant, is there beating between a sinusoidal wave of frequency $f + \Delta f$ and a wave of frequency $n f$, for small $\Delta f$ and integer $n$?  $n = 1$ is the classic case, but what about $n = 2$ and so on?

Comment: I don't really care to write out all the algebra, but I think you can understand this using the double-angle formula: $\sin(x/2)=\sin(x)/(2\cos(x/2))$. So, indeed, there is a component at $x$, which can beat with a nearby frequency and cause the modulation shown in the plot.